# How to create an elliptic text slider in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have a component and it has date. What i am trying to do is when user horizontally scrolls over the days, for example, want them to follow the elliptic shape. Me and my friend tried different ways but could not reach a solution. As seen in the picture, they go linear

[image]

This is the code in the component

```
  const { onChangeValue, initialIndex, data } = props;
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState<string>();
  const [selectedDataIndex, setSelectedDataIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const animatedValues = data.map(() => useSharedValue(0));

  const handleScroll = (event: any) => {
    const offsetX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const selected = Math.round(offsetX / snapSegment) + 1;
    setSelectedDataIndex(selected - 1);
    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
      const start = (index + 3) * snapSegment - spacerWidth;
      const end = (index + 4) * snapSegment - spacerWidth;
      const distanceToCenter = Math.abs(offsetX - (start + end));
      const translateY = Math.max(0, halfSegmentHeight - distanceToCenter);
      const timingValues = [29, 26, 9, -9, -26];
      for (let i = -4; i <= 4; i++) {
        const index = selectedDataIndex + i;
        if (animatedValues[index]) {
          animatedValues[index].value = withSpring(
            (translateY + timingValues[Math.abs(i)]) / halfSegmentHeight
          );
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        snapToInterval={snapSegment}
        style={styles.scrollView}
        bounces={false}
        onScroll={handleScroll}>
        <View style={styles.spacer}></View>
        {data.map((item, index) => {
          const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
            return {
              height: segmentHeight + animatedValues[index].value * 70,
            };
          });

          const animatedTextStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
            return {
              color:
                index === selectedDataIndex
                  ? withTiming("red")
                  : withTiming("white"),
              fontSize:
                index === selectedDataIndex ? withTiming(20) : withTiming(18),
            };
          });
          return (
            <Animated.View style={[styles.item, animatedStyle]} key={index}>
              <Animated.Text style={[styles.itemText, animatedTextStyle]}>
                {item}
              </Animated.Text>
            </Animated.View>
          );
        })}
        <View style={[styles.spacer, { marginRight: 0 }]}></View>
      </ScrollView>
      <View
        style={{
          width: 70,
          height: 50,
          backgroundColor: "#D9D9D9",
          position: "absolute",
          top: 90,
          left: width / 2 - 35,
          zIndex: -10,
          borderRadius: 80,
        }}></View>
    </View>
```

I assume the problem is with `handleScroll` function, but do not know for sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested below and it works.

A combination of useSharedValue,   useAnimatedStyle,  useDerivedValue, and interpolateColor from "react-native-reanimated" would do the job.

[image]

No need for withTiming, as ScrollView is already animated and withTiming would interrupt onScroll results.

When reanimated is runOnUI, it's hooks should start with "worklet";

onMomentumScrollEnd is also required to cover for scrollEventThrottle.

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");
const segmentQty = 5;
const segmentWidth = Math.round(width / segmentQty); // snapToInterval is buggy  with non integers.
const halfWidth = width * 0.5;

const fontSizeMin = 14;
const fontSizeChange = 6;

const scrollHeight = width * 0.3;
const itemHeight = (fontSizeMin + fontSizeChange) * 2;
const translateYMax = scrollHeight - itemHeight;

const sampleList = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, index) => ({
  index,
  key: index,
  text: (index + 1) % 5 ? index + 1 : "buzz",
}));

const getEllipseYAbs = (x, semiX, semiY) => {
  "worklet";
  return Math.sqrt((1 - (x - semiX) ** 2 / semiX ** 2) * semiY ** 2);
};

const getYOnEllipseDown = (localX) => {
  "worklet";
  if (localX < 0 || width < localX) return 0;
  return getEllipseYAbs(localX, halfWidth, translateYMax);
};

const AnimatedItem = ({ index, text, sharedOffsetX }) => {
  const itemMidX = (index + 0.5) * segmentWidth;

  const drivedLocalX = useDerivedValue(() => itemMidX - sharedOffsetX.value);
  const animProgress = useDerivedValue(() => {
    const normalX = Math.abs((drivedLocalX.value - halfWidth) / segmentWidth) * 2;
    return normalX < 1 ? 1 - normalX : 0;
  });

  const animStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    color: interpolateColor(animProgress.value, [0, 1], ["black", "red"]),
    fontSize: fontSizeMin + fontSizeChange * animProgress.value,
    fontWeight: animProgress.value ? "bold" : "normal",
    transform: [{ translateY: getYOnEllipseDown(drivedLocalX.value) }],
  }));

  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Animated.Text style={animStyle}>{text}</Animated.Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const EllipticalScroll = ({ list = sampleList }) => {
  const [selectedDataIndex, setSelectedDataIndex] = useState(0);
  const sharedOffsetX = useSharedValue(0);

  const handleScroll = ({ nativeEvent }, shouldUpdateState = false) => {
    const { x } = nativeEvent.contentOffset;
    sharedOffsetX.value = x;
    if (shouldUpdateState) setSelectedDataIndex(Math.round(x / segmentWidth));
  };
  const handleScrollEnd = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    handleScroll({ nativeEvent }, true);
  };

  const renderItem = (item) => (
    <AnimatedItem {...item} sharedOffsetX={sharedOffsetX} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContent}
        horizontal
        onMomentumScrollEnd={handleScrollEnd}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        snapToInterval={segmentWidth}
        style={styles.scrollView}
      >
        {list.map(renderItem)}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    width,
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    alignItems: "center",
    height: scrollHeight,
    width: segmentWidth,
  },
  scrollView: {
    width,
    height: scrollHeight,
  },
});
```

If Animated.Text is not required, below would animate items on a similar path.

```
const animStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [{ translateY: getYOnEllipseDown(drivedLocalX.value) }],       
  }));

 return (
    <Animated.view style={[styles.item, animStyle]}>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </Animated.view>
  );
```

Also, different worklets could be used instead of getYOnEllipseDown.

getYOnEllipseUp:

```
const getYOnEllipseUp = (localX) => {
  "worklet";
  if (localX < 0 || width < localX) return translateYMax;    
  return translateYMax - getEllipseYAbs(localX, halfWidth, translateYMax);
};
```

getYOnArrowDown:

```
const getYOnArrowDown = (localX) => {
  "worklet";
  if (localX < 0 || width < localX) return 0;    
  return (1 - Math.abs((localX - halfWidth) / halfWidth)) * translateYMax;
};
```

getYOnArrowUp:

```
const getYOnArrowUp = (localX) => {
  "worklet";    
  if (localX < 0 || width < localX) return translateYMax;    
  return Math.abs((localX - halfWidth) / halfWidth) * translateYMax;
};
```